# How to pass a CSS class as input in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use angular2 @Input directive to get a CSS class from another component. Say I have the following:

`<custom-component ngClass="xClass"> </custom-component>`

I have "xClass" in the current component css file, and I want to pass this class as input to the custom-component using @Input like so:

`@Input('dac-class')
 private class: CSS //not sure about this;`

is that possible in one way or another?

Comment: Please refer below url and it may be helpful for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661957/angular2-css-style-class-strings-as-inputs-to-component

Answer (score 0):

```
@Input('dac-class') private Klass: string
```

The word `class` is reserved , so you cannot use it as an alias in javascript or typescript, also , it's always nicer to have input with the same name as the alias .:

```
@Input('dac-class') private decClass: string
```

and then you'd use it :

```
 <custom-component dac-class="someCssClass"  ngClass="xClass"> </custom-component>
```

Comment: When you say `dac-class="someCssClass"` this someCssClass is read as string.

Comment: class should be string, shouldn't it  ? if you want variable , just pass [dac-class]="someCssClass"

Comment: Yes, this would be true if I'm reading this input as object from the .ts file, but this isn't the case. I want to read the css class object with its properties from the .css file

Comment: What do you mean from .css file ? doesn't make any sense, show us some of your code base

Comment: `.xClass {
 width: 20px;
height: 30px;
}` 

this class is in the .css file, I want to pass it to another component as it is