# Angular2 CSS style/class strings as inputs to component

Tags: css, angular

### Background

I have a component that wraps two `span` elements. I would like parent components to be able to style the inner two `span`s by specifying CSS classes and styles as inputs (preferably as simple strings). Here's a simplified example of what I would like this to look like:

### Code

#### app component (parent)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <app-two-spans [classArg1]="'class1'" [classArg2]="'class2'"
                     [styleArg1]="'width: 100px'" [styleArg2]="'width:200px'"></app-two-spans>
    </div>
  `, style: `
    ::ng-deep .class1 {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    ::ng-deep .class2 {
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
  `
})
export class App {

}
```

#### two spans component (child)

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-two-spans',
    template: `
        <span *ngIf="flag" [ngClass]="classArg1" [ngStyle]="styleArg1" 
              (click)="flag = !flag">click me</span>
        <span *ngIf="!flag" [ngClass]="classArg2" [ngStyle]="styleArg2" 
              (blur)="flag = !flag" contenteditable="true">
              click me to change my value</span> 
    `
})
export class TwoSpansComponent {
  flag: boolean = true;
  @Input() styleArg1: string;
  @Input() styleArg2: string;
  @Input() classArg1: string;
  @Input() classArg2: string;
  constructor() {}
}
```

### Problem

The class styling seems to work in my local environment (though it doesn't seem to work on Plunker for some reason). However, the `style`s are not showing up. I've seen other posts about styles as inputs, but from what I've seen this is usually done by passing style-value pairs ([see accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734073/angular2-whats-the-best-way-to-pass-styling-to-a-component)). However, I would really like to pass these styles as a simple string to make working with the component easier.
I notice the following error in the console: `ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'width: 100px'`. I'm not sure what this means at all.

[Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/WmE0hg6XlTxq0reZHZ7X)

Is there a way to do this? How can I give parent components the ability to stylize children?

Comment: You havemistake on the plunker, it should be styles: `` with array instead of `style`

Comment: ^ It is about the components. Also, [ngStyle] accepts objects not strings.

Comment: I guess ng-deep should have :host before to work propely. `:host ::ng-deep .class1 {`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on [ngStyle]. I would still like a way to pass css styles as inputs as simple strings

Comment: I mean that it should always be an array, event if it has one string with all styles inline. @Component decorator doesn't have `style` property.

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://medium.com/the-crazy-coder/how-to-style-child-component-from-parent-in-angular-b829257faba2

Answer (score 1):

`ngStyle` accepts an `Object` instead of plain string. You can pass your styles as:

```
[styleArg1]="{ width: '100px' }"
[styleArg2]="{ width: '200px' }"
```

Comment: Hmm this could a good place to start. Perhaps I can write a function using a regex that converts plain css strings to such an object, so that I can write `[styleArg1]=" 'width: 100px' " as desired`